# In Identity Server 4, how do I read the encrypted refresh token(string) saved in database in order to get the access token?

Tags: identityserver4, refresh-token

I have a Identity Server 4 pool(2 servers), one server is issuing a Access token(JWT) and also a Refresh token, Refresh token is saved in database table.(PersistedGrants table). Now when the Access token expires, I want to read the Refresh token from second Server and call RequestRefreshTokenAsync to get back a new set of tokens.. How do I read the database refresh token in application?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but the`refresh_token` in the client gets translated to the database `Id` on IdentityServer4's `PersistedGrants` table by using the following code I believe I had extracted from the IdentityServer4's source code some time ago:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace HandleToKey
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No argument provided, you may want to provide with a token handle.");
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: HandleToKey.exe [tokenHandle]");
            }
            else
            {
                var input = args.First();
                using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
                {
                    input = $"{input}:refresh_token";
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                    var hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
                    var result = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant bytes are the code inside the using which I think (I don't remember) is the code used to create and consult a persisted grant in the actual source code, or similar to it. It concatenates the input with `":refresh_token"`, gets a `byte[]` using UTF8 charmap, and computes its `SHA256` hash, then encodes it in Base64, and the result should be the Id.

You could also get the same result with an access_token reference by changing the string to `":access_token"` instead of refresh_token.

Anyway I've only used this for debugging purposes. **I would like you to avoid using this code on a production site**, because I'm sure there's a better way of solving your actual problem if you let us know more about it.

Comment: The code I am using for Identity server 4 is simlar to the one in here

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/9_Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage


This saves the data to the [PersistedGrants] table, the table has the follwing columns
[Key],[Type],[SubjectId],[ClientId],[CreationTime],[Expiration],[Data]

The Key column sis the one whihc holds the refresh token.

Now, I want to use this token to get a new set of tokens.(In Production scenario, I can't depend on in-memory tokens.)

Comment: The refresh_token issued and the key on the database, are not the same. That's exactly what my code does, transforms the refresh_token into the database Key. There's no way AFAIK to do it the other way arround, ie: take the Key and obtain the actual refresh_token or tokenHandle